# Не получается наполнить список случайными значениями

Tags: python, list

Случайным образом вытаскиваем из файла 3 значения, которые не повторяются.
Затем необходимо заполнить список. Но список заполняется одинаковыми строками, а надо чтобы разными. Подскажите, что делаю не так?

```
for i in skills_all:
    skills_all = sample(skills_all, 3)
    skill_1 = skills_all[0]
    skill_2 = skills_all[1]
    skill_3 = skills_all[2]

all_skills = []
for b in range(10):
    all_skills.append(skill_1)
    all_skills.append(skill_2)
    all_skills.append(skill_3)
```

Comment: Оставьте только второй цикл, в него добавьте код из первого цикла. Что сейчас делаете не так - после первого цикла у вас в skill_1 - skill_3 остаются записаны значения (последние значения). Во втором цикле вы не изменяя эти значения заполняете во все элементы all_skills. Вместо этого на каждой итерации второго цикла заново нужно получать новые случайные значения.

Comment: Или сразу сделайте `sample` нужного размера. Задача плохо сформулирована, непонятно, нужно все значения разные или только внутри тройки чтобы разные были?

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за обратную связь. Очень помогли!

Comment: @CrazyElf, внутри тройки. спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто совместите второй цикл с кодом из первого цикла, который у вас и не используется как цикл:

```py
all_skills = []
for b in range(10):
    all_skills.extend(sample(skills_all, 3)))
```